# What is wrong with this Microsoft Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Consider this Access query:

```
SELECT prod_Parts.ID, prod_Parts.Number, prod_Parts.Revision, prod_Parts.Description
FROM prod_JT_Shipping 
INNER JOIN (prod_JobTraveller 
            INNER JOIN prod_Parts
                ON prod_JobTraveller.PartID = prod_Parts.ID) 
    ON prod_JT_Shipping.JT_ID=prod_JobTraveller.ID;
```

Also this:

```
 SELECT prod_Parts.ID, prod_Parts.Number, prod_Parts.Revision, prod_Parts.Description 
 FROM prod_Parts;
```

This error occurs on both:

> 'is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long

How can this be fixed?

Comment: If you think your query is OK and Access thinks it isn't, it isn't.

Comment: All code is guilty until proven innocent.  No exceptions.

Comment: Well, if your query is OK, what are you doing here?

Comment: This query works for me in the query design window, are you sure that this is the query taht is causing the problem?

Comment: I believe that it's Ok assuming that something is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the error message, you have some invisible control character in the query, that is causing the problem.

Try to retyping the query from scratch, and it will most likely work.

Side note: I find it easier to follow the joins if they are written in this order (i.e. with the ON clause directly following each JOIN):

```
SELECT
  prod_Parts.ID, prod_Parts.Number, prod_Parts.Revision, prod_Parts.Description
FROM
  (
    prod_JT_Shipping
    INNER JOIN prod_JobTraveller ON prod_JT_Shipping.JT_ID=prod_JobTraveller.ID
  )
  INNER JOIN prod_Parts ON prod_JobTraveller.PartID = prod_Parts.ID
```

Comment: I considered it. I did it before asking

Comment: Have you tried a stripped table? Have you check for corruption?

Answer (score 1):

This part here doesn't look right:

```
INNER JOIN (prod_JobTraveller 
INNER JOIN prod_Parts ON prod_JobTraveller.PartID = prod_Parts.ID)
```

If you consolidate that without whitespace it looks like

```
INNER JOIN (prod_JobTraveller INNER JOIN prod_Parts ON prod_JobTraveller.PartID = prod_Parts.ID)
```

Which is not valid SQL.

Comment: It is legal to group joins using parentheses, though I've used it so rarely that I can't say for sure whether the OP's query is valid or not, but I think it is valid.

Comment: Doesn't work. Access breaks lines. I wrong copied and pasted. Anyway problem is presented

Comment: A straight cut-and-paste of the OP query into SQL view of the query design window will run.

Comment: Grouping joins with parentheses is not only valid, it's actually required in Access if you have more than one join.

Comment: How is that invalid SQL? There's nothing wrong with it so far as I can see. Please explain exactly what characters in the SQL clause are invalid, or I'll downvote your answer. If you find you're mistaken, then just delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have simplified query:

SELECT prod_Parts.ID, prod_Parts.Number, prod_Parts.Revision, prod_Parts.Description FROM prod_Parts;

The same error :)

Comment: Is `prod_Parts` a base table or a `VIEW` (persisted Query object)? Either way, posting SQL DDL to recreate it would help. `Number` is a reserved word in Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) but qualifying it in the SELECT clause with the table name shouldn't cause a problem.